# tensorflow, how to join SparseTensor with type tf.string

Tags: string, tensorflow

tensorflow has tf.string_split function that can split dense tensor to SparseTensor, but not provided the opposite function.

anyone knows how to do it? thanks~

below is one method, but i don't know how to assign the value of num_split dynamically when compute slice_input_list

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_dense = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None], name='input_sentences')
split_input_dense = tf.string_split(input_dense)

# slice_input_list = tf.sparse_split(sp_input=split_input_dense, num_split=split_input_dense.get_shape()[0], axis=0)
# slice_input_list = tf.sparse_split(sp_input=split_input_dense, num_split=split_input_dense.dense_shape[0], axis=0)
slice_input_list = tf.sparse_split(sp_input=split_input_dense, num_split=3, axis=0)

join_input_list = []
for slice_input in slice_input_list:
  slice_input_value = slice_input.values
  join_input = tf.reduce_join(slice_input_value, reduction_indices=0, separator=' ')
  join_input_list.append(join_input)
output_dense = tf.stack(join_input_list)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  feed_dict = {input_dense: np.array(["a b c", "d e", "f g h i"])}
  print sess.run(output_dense, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```